# ActiveStorage attachment not associated after reload in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activestorage

I want to test that a file is correctly being attached to a record.

I have a Notification model with a thumbnail.

```rb
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :thumbnail
end
```

I'm using sidekiq through active job.

```rb
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```

I have set storage adapter to the local file system and perform jobs immediately

```rb
# config/environments/test.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_storage.service = :test
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
end
```

I have the following spec using capybara and selenium:

```rb
      it 'creates the model' do
        click_on class: 'create-action'

        attach_file('notification[thumbnail]', Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/uploads/notification_thumbnail.jpg'))
        fill_in 'notification[title]', with: 'MyString'

        expect do
          click_on 'Create notification'
        end.to change { ActiveStorage::Attachment.count }.by(1)

        new_notification = Notification.order(created_at: :desc).first

        expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t('successfully_created_resource', resource: 'MyString'))

        new_notification.reload

        expect(new_notification.thumbnail).to be_attached
     end
```

To investigate further I created a simple spec:

```rb
    it 'has an attached thumbnail' do
      notification = build(:notification)
      notification.thumbnail = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/uploads/notification_thumbnail.jpg'), 'image/jpg')
      notification.save

      puts ActiveStorage::Blob.order(created_at: :desc).first.attachments.inspect
      expect(notification.thumbnail).to be_attached
      expect(notification.reload.thumbnail).to be_attached
    end
```

The first expectation always passes, the latter sometimes fails.

When looking at the attachment it has `record_id` `0`

```rb
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 1, name: "thumbnail", record_type: "Notification", record_id: 0, blob_id: 1, created_at: "2020-11-30 10:40:28">]>
```

Can anyone explain this behavior to me and give me pointers on how do avoid it / write tests properly?

Comment: Could it be a race condition? `attach` actually inserts the row into the blobs table and then a callback in your Notification model added by `has_one_attached` updates the blob with an id when you save the record. If that read query finishes before the update query you could be getting stale data. Does it change the result or start flapping if you add `sleep(10)`?

Comment: The result does not change regardless of the setting of `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline`

Comment: @max https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913652/attachments-adding-duplicates-in-active-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While investigating a different bug I realized ActiveStorage was not set up for usage with UUIDs as the [big red box in the setup section](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup) warns about.

```rb
2.7.0 :001 > "2a".to_i
 => 2
2.7.0 :002 > "a2".to_i
 => 0
```